# why is my command line argument can take "2x" although I make the condition that it can only take integer

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, cs50

I have another question about my caesar code-enchipering programs. Here I specified, that I want to take only integer. But somehow it proceed when 2x is inputted in the command line arguments.

Below is the full code... I deeply appreciate it if anyone can help me answer my question.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//one command line argument with the type int
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    //main program
    if (argc == 2 && isdigit(*argv[1]))
    {
        int k = atoi(argv[1]);                                                      //get Caesar key into a variable
        
        string pltext = get_string("plaintext: ");                                  //getting input for the plain text
        char cptext[strlen(pltext) + 1];

        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(pltext) ; i < n; i++)                            //turning pltext to integer
        {
            if (pltext[i] >= 'a' && pltext[i] <= 'z')
            {
                cptext[i] = ((pltext[i] - 'a' + k) % 26) + 'a';                     //shifting the integer with k (lowercase)
            }
            else if (pltext[i] >= 'A' && pltext[i] <= 'Z')
            {
                cptext[i] = ((pltext[i] - 'A' + k) % 26) + 'A';                     //shifting the integer with k (uppercase)
            }
            else
            {
                cptext[i] = pltext[i];                                              //other symbol stays
            }
        }
        //print out result
        printf("ciphertext: %s\n", cptext);
        return 0;
    }
    //setting condition that : K = + ; if more or less than one, immediate error message, return 1
    //if not decimal return = usage ./caesar. key, return value 1 to main
    else if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Error 404 : \n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: and where is the code?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger or other tool?

Comment: What do you think `isdigit(*argv[1])` means?

Comment: I think that isdigit(*argv[1]) refer to the second (place 1) command line argument array and check if it is a digit. I have tried stepping through with a debugger and the problem lay in the condition I think. But I don't know the solution.

Comment: Not quite. It checks whether the first character of it is a digit. Note that `argv[1]` is`"2x"`, but `*argv[1]` is `'2'`.

Comment: Given that, do you see how you'd have to adjust your code for it to check the whole thing? Also, have you considered using `strtol` instead of having to check yourself and use `atoi`?

Answer (score 1):

The `isdigit` function only checks the first digit. meaning if I use 2x, itll see 2. what you could do is put a loop, checking the digits in the key given by the user, and see if each one is a digit!

Answer (score -2):

argv[ ] in your program is char * (acc to cs50 header), so first element is a pointer to array of char's , in C programming language if you de-reference a pointer to array you get the first element in your array.
so in your program when you de-reference pointer to string "2x" ex : *argv[1], you get first element of that string (array of chars) which is 2 ! so this returning true (or 1 in this case ) and continuing that conditional statement :)

```
char * string = "2x";
if (string[0] == *string) print("this is the bug in your program!");
```

Comment: "1 . arguments to isdigit() is int or char, you seem to be passing char[] or char * depending on header definiton of string in cs50.h" This is wrong. A regular char is indeed being passed to isdigit().

Comment: you are correct, i think the updated answer better answers the solution :)

Comment: "try adding an other conditional statement ex : strlen(argv[1]) == 1 this might fix your problem !" Then passing `12` or `20` wouldn't work.

Comment: But I do want to be able to take input of higher numbers. what I don't want is a combination of number and char like 2x. But it must not be specified. It can be 2y 2z or anything of the kind. the solution you give give a condition specific to 2x.

Comment: @Bluesky21800: If you want to check all digits in a string, you will have to program a loop to check every single character in the string with the function `isdigit`. You will have to program this yourself, as the C standard library does not provide a function for this (it is a simple loop, though). You may want to program your own function `int does_string_contain_only_digits( char *str )`, which behaves like `isdigit` except it accepts strings as a parameter instead of individual characters. For this, you should not be using the data type `string` though. You should use `char*` instead.

Comment: @Bluesky21800: The CS50 course only provides the data type `string` as "training wheels" and tells you to use `char *` instead at a certain point. In order to solve your problem, I'm afraid that you will have to advance to that point in the course. All of this is explained in [this video of the CS50 course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cF6YkH-8vFk). In the text below the video, you will find a table of contents. Although I strongly suggest that you watch the whole video, you should specificially look at the sections "Strings Don't Exist" and "char *".

Comment: @prajwaltr: "argv[ ] in your program is char *" - This statement of yours does not make sense to me, as the brackets are not part of the variable name. The name of the variable is `argv`, not `argv[]`. The brackets are part of the type declaration, but only a part. The data type of `argv` is `char **` (which is equivalent to `char (*)[]` when used as a function parameter).

Comment: @prajwaltr: You may want to additionally mention in your answer that `*argv[1]` is equivalent to `argv[1][0]`, instead of only describing this in words. Describing it in words is good, but it may be clearer if you also write it as code.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel "argv[] in your program is char *" by this i meant argv is array of char *

Comment: @AndreasWenzel i have given a sample code describing it.